# laptop does not boot

Tags: laptop

I have hp probook 4520s lap. But now it does not boot. When I press switch on button fans are working but it shows black screen. HDD light just blink one or two times when start but it will not continue. And usually web cam light should blink one time when startup but it doesn't. I connect to different monitor but couldn't see a output.

This lap bought 3 months before but it doesn't have international warranty. Therefore I can not do anything. If someone can provide any clue or suggestion that what happened and what should I do, appreciated.

thank you.

Comment: Annoying, but this place is not for hardware issues.

Comment: Do you see any other blinking LEDs on the laptop and are they blinking in a pattern?  If so, it may help determine exactly what part of the laptop has stopped working.

Comment: I would try reseating the cpu and memory first.

Answer (score 1):

If the machine got dropped or a bit of a knock, it might have unseated the memory.  You could try opening up the memory socket and take out the memory and reseat it.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes removing the battery and starting it with the powersupply connected helps.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try booting into bios.
While starting, hit the F8 or the delete key a few times, (depends on your settings) and see if you startup into bios.